# Yii, relation with same name as FK, renaming field

Tags: php, yii, orm

I have a problem with my model, because I have a relationship that has the same name as the FK column.

```
class Post extends CActiveRecord {
  public function relations() {
    return array(
      'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user')
    );
  }
}
```

How do I map the `user` column to something else, so that I can access both the relation and the FK under different names? I cannot modify the database column, because other applications depend on it.

I want to be able to do this:

```
$post = Post::findByPk(1);
$post->user_id; // returns foreign key
$post->user; // returns activerecord
```

Below implementation would also be fine, but using above relation Yii just returns `[0=>1242]` for `$post->user`.

```
$post->user;
$post->user->user_id;
```

I specifically do NOT want something like this:

```
$post->user; // Returns FK
$post->userobject; // Returns ActiveRecord. Ugly!
```

TLDR: how do i map a FK column to a different attribute so it doesn't conflict with a relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i see your FK in Post model to User model is `user_id` rather than `user`.

```
$post->user_id; // returns foreign key
```

If it's not so, just modify your Post model to this form, where `user_id` keeps id of related User model.

So then you make relation this way:

```
public function relations() {
 return array(
  'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id')
 );
}
```

Now there should not be conflicts and you'll be able to do as desired:

```
$post = Post::findByPk(1);
$post->user_id; // returns foreign key
$post->user; // returns activerecord
```

### Update

I've just noticed:

> I cannot modify the database column, because other applications depend on it.

Kind of poor application design.

> I specifically do NOT want something like this:

```
$post->user; // Returns FK
$post->userobject; // Returns ActiveRecord. Ugly!
```

> how do i map a FK column to a different attribute so it doesn't conflict with a relation

I wouldn't do things like this:

```
function getUser_id(){
    return $this->user;
}
```

Seems unresolvable situation, cause you try to avoid `$post->userobject`!

How about `$post->userModel` ?
If you insist on keeping `user` FK and `user` as related model reference you'll get into long term rut.

Comment: `$post->related_user` for model object looks more semantic :)